# Two-step git import over ssh

Tags: git, import, ssh, bitbucket

Bitbucket has an importer tool for importing repositories from remote locations, but it only supports the `git://` protocol. Our existing repositories are on a company controlled machine behind a firewall that I can't change, and `git://` is not available. I need to move the repositories from our company machine to bitbucket, keeping all history and details from the original repository intact.

Is there some way I can accomplish this by cloning the original repository via ssh to a local machine, and then pushing that repository to a newly-bare-initted repository on bitbucket? Will I lose any history or data that way?

(I'm hoping for an answer that isn't bitbucket specific, but will work for "moving" a git repository in any case.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to be sure you have the *entire* history. You can do this by performing a full local bare clone first.

```
git clone --mirror git://LOCAL_URL/somerepo.git
```

Then add the remote and push as Timothy pointed out. Though, you probably want to use something other than origin for the remote alias.

```
git remote add bitbucket ssh://git@bitbucket.org/someuser/somerepo.git
git push -u bitbucket --all
```

This could be used for any Git hosting service. Simply replace the remote URL with anything you'd like.

Comment: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Answer (score 6):

From what I know cloning the entire repo and pushing it works. Bitbucket even has the command for you:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/someuser/somerepo.git
git push -u origin --all   # to push changes for the first time
```

Comment: Use the clone command like Marcus suggested if you want the entire history.

Answer (score -1):

What makes you think that we only support the git:// protocol? We support the smart http protocol and so for instance you can just import https://github.com/jquery/jquery

So if your repo is accessible from the Internet and does HTTP(S) then you should have no problem using the importer (which does a proper clone and do preserves history).